# get source html in local system python

Tags: python, urlopen

Dears I want get source page but not in internet rather in local system

```
example : url=urllib.request.urlopen ('c://1.html')



>>> import urllib.request
>>> url=urllib.request.urlopen ('http://google.com')
>>> page =url.read()
>>> page=page.decode()
>>> page
```

what's my problem ?

Comment: 'c://1.html' is not a valid url

Comment: I know but I need get source in local system

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_url

Comment: @aliweb why can you just open the file and read it?

Comment: @Hypuk Thank you file://localhost/c|/WINDOWS/file.postfix

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It makes no sense programmatically... All you do is tell `urllib` to do what i wrote below :S

Comment: @Torxed for tutorial in school ;) because we in school Not  access Internet

Comment: @aliweb You failed to mentioned that in the question there for my suspicious questions. Sorry about that and Hypuk could write an answer and score the points :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from os.path import abspath
with open(abspath('c:/1.html') as fh:
    print(fh.read())
```

Since `url.read()` just gives you the data as-is, and `.decode()` doesn't really do anything except convert the byte data from the socket to a traditional string, just print the filecontents?

`urllib` is mainly (if not only) a transporter to recieve HTML data, not actually parse the content. So all it does is connect to the source, separate the headers and give you the content. If you've already stored it locally, in a file.. Well then `urllib` has no more use to you. Consider looking at a HTML Parsing library such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for instance.